# Crystal Reports for VS2010 in Windows 7 Pro - Load report failed

Tags: crystal-reports

Everything is OK in win7 Ultimate x32, but I cannot use the same code with CR for VS2010 in win7 pro x64.
My code:

```
        ReportDocument doc = null;
        try
        {
            doc = new ReportDocument();
            doc.Load("D:\\CrystalReport4.rpt");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
        finally
        {
            if (doc != null)
            {
                doc.Close();
                doc.Dispose();
            }
        }
```

Always throw exception:

```
CrystalDecisions.Shared.CrystalReportsException: Load report failed. ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: The system cannot find the path specified.

   at CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ClientDoc.ReportClientDocumentClass.Open(Object& DocumentPath, Int32 Options)
   at CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ReportClientDocumentWrapper.Open(Object& DocumentPath, Int32 Options)
   at CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ReportClientDocumentWrapper.EnsureDocumentIsOpened()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ReportClientDocumentWrapper.EnsureDocumentIsOpened()
   at CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument.Load(String filename, OpenReportMethod openMethod, Int16 parentJob)
   at CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument.Load(String filename)
   at CrystalReportsApplication1.Form1.button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in J:\Projects\CrystalReportsApplication1\CrystalReportsApplication1\Form1.cs:line 33
```

The path to rpt file is correct. I don't know why inner exception show: The system cannot find the path specified.

My machine install: 
- SAP Crystal Reports, version for Visual Studio 2010 
- SAP Crystal Reports, runtime engine for .Net Framework 4 (64bit)
All of them are SP1, version in GAC: 13.0.2000.0

Anyone can help me fix this issue?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try installing the 32 Bit version on the 64 Bit computer. I don't know if the error was the same but I had a similar problem with running some reports that were written by a third party. Installing the 32 bit runtime version fixed it for me.